# Footer with page numbers

Tags: header-footer

I have to write an exam for my administration. They want a footer on each page containing the following information:

[image]

The only element that has to change is in the lower right: page number and the total number of pages.

I searched for examples (but don't know how to translate "cartouche" into English), and read the documentation of `fancyhdr`, but didn't understand everything. I would prefer an example showing what can be done or some links to examples, if they exist.

Comment: That's a "footer" not a "footnote"; you might want to reword the question.

Comment: This is not hard. Just use a standard footer, the pagenumber can be inserted as a variable. If you need to calculate the total number of pages, take a look at the `lastpage` package.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this will get you started: adjust as necessary. (And obviously you can remove the `\usepackage{tgheros}` and `\sffamily` if you don't want it in sans font: I was just trying to emulate the picture.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lastpage}% to reference total page number
\usepackage{tgheros}% approximates font in your image
% reset style
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}% pages have the fancy footer by default
\fancyhf{}
% for the footer
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{%
\sffamily\footnotesize% for smaller sans serif font
\def\arraystretch{1.7}% put some vertical padding in cells
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}% put some horizontal padding in cells
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
2023 & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{BTS SIO} & Sujet \\ \hline
     & E21 Mathématiques pour l'informatique & Coef: 2 & Durée : 2 h 00 & \thepage\ / \pageref{LastPage} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}% no footer first page
\lipsum[1-50]% dummy text
\thispagestyle{plain}% simpler footer last page
\end{document}
```

[image: footer example]

Comment: Very nice ! Exactly what I wanted... except for the table not being centered in my page, as it is in yours :-)

Comment: You can post your code in an edit to your question in the form of a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that reproduces the problem of it not being centered and maybe we can figure out why…

Comment: Never mind, I figured out a workaround, working with the \tabcolsep parameter you provided ;-) Works like a charm, thank you very much.